# Can I set a different color for the weekend on monthly fullCalendar display

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How does one go about setting the weekend to a different color when viewing the monthly or weekly view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously this will depend entirely on your HTML, but assuming you are using a table with class `calendar`, with the weekends at the right:

```
$('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(-n+2)').addClass('weekend');
```

`-n+2` selects the last 2 table cells in each row. `weekend` is a class, so in your CSS you'd have something like:

```
.weekend { color: #00f; }
```

(If your HTML is different, then update your question with a better description and the code.)

Answer (score 23):

I think that for the case of FullCalendar, you just need to specify some CSS for the existing CSS classes:

```
.fc-sat { color:blue; }
.fc-sun { color:red;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this, the latest versions of FullCalendar have the following stylings:

```
/* Highlight the weekends */
.fc-day-sat, .fc-day-sun {
    background-color: #e4ece4;
}
```

It goes by "fc-day" now, with the day in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to gray-out weekends.

```
.fc td.fc-sun, .fc td.fc-sat { background-color:#dddddd; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if we want to color only weekends not friday 
i tried this  .fc-nonbusiness {
    background-color:white;}

```
.fc-sat {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    color:
}

.fc-sun {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

for full-calendar