# Color weekend at Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar component  and I need to color the weekends ,Friday & Saturday.
I have used the following as recommended here: 
[Can I set a different color for the weekend on monthly fullCalendar display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044482/different-color-for-weekend-on-monthly-fullcalendar-display)

```
$('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(-n+2)').addClass('fc-weekend');
```

I added as well the css class.

Here is me code that doesn't color the weekends ... Any advise!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $.getJSON('[@spring.url '/loadSomeData'/]', function (data) {
      $.getJSON('[@spring.url '/loadOtherData/]', function (info) {
        information = returnedPublicVacation;

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          select:
            function(start, end, allDay) {
              vacationStart = start;
              showTheCorrectDialog(vacationStart);
            },

          eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            showTheCorrectDialog(calEvent.start);

            // change the border color just for fun
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
          },

          editable: true,
          events:data.concat(information)
        });
        resourceVacation = data;
      });
    });

    $('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(-n+2)').addClass('fc-weekend');
  });
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you add style to the class in your css file?

You might also try this:

```
.fc-fri { color:blue; }
.fc-sat { color:red;  }
```

(or .fc-sun for Sunday)
You can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh13yadav/nf9whojL/1/

Comment: I have removed my css class for "fc-weekend" and I've added yours. It colorize the number not the whole cell !

Comment: I used :.fc-fri { color:blue; background-color:blue }

Comment: But how does it work !! ... I ahve removed the JQuery line and it works fine and the cells are colorized :$('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(-n+2)').addClass('fc-weekend');    ... Do you know how !!

Comment: fullcalendar adds .fc-day (mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun) automatically upon calendar creation so you don't need to do anything by yourself. You just have to style it. `color` is attribute for font color! DON'T use the same color for both font color and background color (change either `color:value` or `background-color:value`.

Comment: That makes sense now as I was searching for ".fc-fri" @ fullcalendar css.Thanks.

Comment: But Its will not color the next month weakend because at that time next month is not in DOM.so is there any alternative

Comment: try class fc-day-sun

Comment: @Aadam is rigth, that is the real class name. Perhaps on the answer, the class names are out-of-date.

Answer (score 5):

In version 4 you can add an event for all Sundays or another days together using "**daysOfWeek**".

```
    events: [
    {
      daysOfWeek: [0,6], //Sundays and saturdays
      rendering:"background",
      color: "#ff9f89",
      overLap: false,
      allDay: true
    }]
```

I recommend that you use this method because you can easily change it with server-side scripting languages (like PHP, Node.js, JavaScript, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
.fc-sun { 
color:#337ab7;  
border-color: black;  
background-color: #ffa58c; }
```

Comment: try class fc-day-sun for 5.*

Answer (score 3):

***SOLUTION IN FULLCALENDAR VERSION 5:***

Apply CSS style to the ***fc-day-sat*** and ***fc-day-sun*** class:

```
#calendar .fc-day-sun, #calendar .fc-day-sat {
    background-color: #f4f5d7;
}
```

If you don't want to change the color of calendar header (which display the "Sat" and "Sun"), u can precisely apply the css for the ***fc-day-sat*** and ***fc-day-sun*** class by adding ***td*** tag:

```
#calendar td.fc-day-sun, #calendar td.fc-day-sat {
    background-color: #f4f5d7;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In fullcalendar version 5**

The css class for days has been changed as given below.

**.fc-sun -> .fc-day-sun**

**.fc-mon -> .fc-day-mon**

**.fc-tue -> .fc-day-tue**

**.fc-wed -> .fc-day-wed**

**.fc-thu -> .fc-day-thu**

**.fc-fri -> .fc-day-fri**

**.fc-sat -> .fc-day-sat**

**So you can use like (For sunday)**

```
.fc-day-sun {
    background-color: red;
    /*your styles goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AJS.$(document).ready(function () {
    AJS.$(".fc-weekend-column").each(function(i,el){
        AJS.$(this).css("background-color", "#FFF7F7");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fullcalendar version 5:**

`.fc-sat` and `.fc-sun` has been converted to `.fc-day-sat` and `.fc-day-sun`.

Also applying bgcolor to `.fc-day-sat, .fc-day-sat` will not work anymore, because they have applied bgcolor to `.fc-non-business` which is the deepest child class.

> [image]

```
.fc .fc-non-business {  
  background-color: #fff; 
}
```

A common class will do the job now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the top layer of the weekend, use the following code

```
.fc-day-sat .fc-daygrid-day-frame .fc-daygrid-day-bg .fc-daygrid-bg-harness{
        display: none;
}

.fc-day-other .fc-daygrid-day-frame .fc-daygrid-day-bg .fc-daygrid-bg-harness{
    display: block;
}

.fc-day-other .fc-daygrid-day-frame .fc-daygrid-day-bg .fc-daygrid-bg-harness .fc-non-business{
    display: none;
}
```

You can use this code after that:
[Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918387/color-weekend-at-fullcalendar/13918858#13918858)