# Full calendar: change background of weekends

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'am trying to disable weekends in full calendar but this option weekends:false

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {

        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

    weekends: false,
    ........});
```

delete weekends from the calendar or i want to disable only the two days by change the background color and make them unselectable.
what should i  do? 
thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color weekend at Fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918387/color-weekend-at-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you want:

1. show week-ends in a different color
2. know if the day is a week end day

First point, you can use css rules to style the week-end elements:

```
.fc-sat, .fc-sun {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Second point, you can check if the selected date is a week end, and act as you want.
You can use the `dayClick` (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) event in this way:

> ```
> dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent) {
>     var checkDay = new Date($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
>     if (checkDay.getDay() == 6 || checkDay.getDay() == 0) alert('Weekend!');
> }
> ```

You can't disable a day because FullCalendar is not a datepicker, so you can't "disable", but you can handle everything you want.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qLUFg/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot Irvin Dominin :)

Comment: Keep in mind that in some cultures the week doesn't start on Sunday so in the UK for example (where weeks start on Monday) you'd be checking for 5 and 6, instead of 6 and 0. This, of course, is a little wacky and that's why there is the `firstDay` option on FullCalendar, which is culture dependent. See http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/

Comment: .fc-mon {
   background-color: #E09693;
  }
  .fc-tue {
   background-color: #E8E58E;
  }
  .fc-wed {
   background-color: #DAD6B0;
  }
  .fc-thu {
   background-color: #C9E8A8;
  }
  .fc-fri{
   background-color: #9DB3DF;
  }
  .fc-sat {
   background-color: #E09693;
  }
  .fc-sun {
   background-color: #E8E58E;
  }

Comment: Great solution! The newest version of FC uses the class: .fc-day-sat

Comment: In addition, you can use some opacity in the background, in order the row border in the back to be visible. Example: .fc-day-sat, .fc-day-sun {  background: #d0dac433; }

Answer (score 3):

Addition to Irvin Dominin's answer:

Sometimes the first part of the answer above can cause the widget-header to become the same color. So, in order to only address the weekend day cells, use the following styling:

```
.fc-sat,
.fc-sun {
  &.fc-day {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the color of both weekend days, I suggest:

```
.fc-nonbusiness {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This did not work in my case. Perhaps it needs to be specified on the calendar declaration, that the weekend days are non-business?

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @Irvin Dominin , I post mine based on it, because seems to be out-of-date on the names of the classes. And in my case, I also do not want the headers to be colored the same way:

###### Month view:

```
.fc-day-sun .fc-daygrid-day-frame, .fc-day-sat .fc-daygrid-day-frame {
    background-color: #EFF1F5; /* choose whatever color you like */
}
```

###### Week and day views:

```
.fc-day-sun .fc-timegrid-col-frame, .fc-day-sat .fc-timegrid-col-frame {
    background-color: #EFF1F5; /* choose whatever color you like */
}
```

#### Different approach

I did not found a class on the day element itself which is not used also in the header, but I found one `.fc-col-header-cell` which is used on the header, but not on the day instances. And this way, we can do the styling in only one go:

```
.fc-day-sun:not(.fc-col-header-cell), .fc-day-sat:not(.fc-col-header-cell) {
    background-color: #EFF1F5;    /* choose whatever color you like */
}
```

I have a bit of a dislike of using the `:not(...)` declarations on CSS, but I didn't find a better approach yet for my purpose.